# opencv build failed with xcode

Tags: c++, xcode, opencv

I have a problem with a webcam capturing in opencv.

This can be built successfully:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
using namespace cv;

int main() {
//    VideoCapture cap(0);
//    while(true){
//        Mat Webcam;
//        cap.read(Webcam);
//        imshow("Webcam", Webcam);
//    }
}
```

However, this is not:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
using namespace cv;

int main() {
    VideoCapture cap(0);
    while(true){
        Mat Webcam;
        cap.read(Webcam);
        imshow("Webcam", Webcam);
    }
}
```

There is no error or warning message popped out, so I can't solve it by myself.

Any idea is appreciated!

Updates:

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3VZ2R.png)

It seems something went wrong when I updated xcode.....

[Error message 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/idA32.png)

Comment: Can you please add screen shot? Code seems ok and build at my end. Please have a look into linking proper libraries. Need a bit clarification of your problem....

Answer (score 0):

Your code is perfectly ok except following line after imshow:

```
waitKey(10);
```

It will provide ui thread to draw the frames. Without this delay ui thread can not be updated or get time slice from cpu.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I've added "waitKey(10)", but still don't work.......
The pictures fo the build phases and linked libraries are uploaded, please take a look, thanks a lot!

Comment: Is it possible that I didn't build my opencv properly?
I uncheck the "BUILD_TESTS", "WITH_1394", "WITH_FFMPEG".

Comment: Please use pre-built libraries if you have confusion on building process....if certain flags are not on, it could create issues....

Comment: FFMPEG support requires to write videos. Please see the link http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/videoio/doc/reading_and_writing_video.html

Comment: I've rebuilt the opencv again with all the default settings and there is an error in the function imshow(). I'll keep trying.

Comment: I do the whole process several times, and it works.......I don't know why